# Microsoft Update Services WSUS API

Tags: windows, windows-update

I'm working with `WSUS API`, and i'm just a beginner in this.
I have configured WSUS in server 2008 machine. And i'm also getting the list of available updates. Now my work is to find every information of a particular patch with the help of `WSUS API`.
With the help of example provided in the `WSUS API` tool i'am able to extract the title, release date, category type and some other information. But these two information "downloadURL" of a patch and Target OS of a patch (what i meant is a particular patch is applicable for which OS for windows 7 x64 or for  windows 8 x86 ??????) I'm not able to get. I tried looking in `Iupdate` interface but still no luck.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The downloadURL(s) you should find in IUpdate -> DownloadContents -> IUpdateDownloadContent Entries

Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386120(v=vs.85).aspx

For the targetOS, I am not so sure if there is a way to find out.